# How to reset a form control in angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-forms

We have a list of dropdowns and when ever a dropdown is changed, I will show a button by its side. To do this, i am using formcontrol dirty feature. Initially the button is hidden, and when the dropdown becomes dirty, I will sho the button.

But once a button is clicked, all the remaining buttons should be hidden again along with other dropdowns reset to their initial value. How to accomplish this task, because as per my understanding there is no way to make a dirty field as undirty.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <h4 >Person {{i+1}}</h4>
                                <div >
                                    <div ><label class="control-label">Position</label></div>
                                    <div>
                                        <select [ngModel]="staff.position" (ngModelChange)="newPosition=$event;btn.hidden=0" #select="ngModel" name="position" placeholder="position">
                                            <option *ngFor="let i of instituteObj.academic_staff;let i=index" [value]="i+1">{{i+1}}</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div #btn [hidden]="!select.dirty" class="academic-move"><button (click)="changeStaffPosition(staff.position,newPosition);btn.hidden=1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Move</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div><br>
```

and my component function are:

```
changeStaffPosition(currentPosition,newPosition){
    if(currentPosition < newPosition){
      for(let staff of this.instituteObj.academic_staff){
        if(staff.position > currentPosition && staff.position <= newPosition){
          --staff.position;
        }
      }
      this.instituteObj.academic_staff[currentPosition-1]['position'] = newPosition;  
    }
    else{
      for(let staff of this.instituteObj.academic_staff){
        if(staff.position >= newPosition && staff.position < currentPosition){
          ++staff.position;
        }
      }
      this.instituteObj.academic_staff[currentPosition-1]['position'] = newPosition;
    }

    this.instituteObj.academic_staff.sort((a,b) => {
      if(a['position']<b['position']){return -1}
      if(a['position']>b['position']){return 1}
      return 0;
    });
}
```

Basically the problem i am trying to solve is to make the user set the ordering of a list using the dropdowns where every list item has a dropdown, once the user chooses a position and clicks move button, the list reorders with new order.

Answer (score 4):

You can call use `AbstractControl.markAsPristing()`

```
select.markAsPristine();
```

To do it from your component class you need a reference to the control first like

```
@ViewChild('select') select;

...

this.select.markAsPristine();
```

Just saw, this is only available in the new forms module of RC.4.
The docs don't show this yet. Maybe it only becomes available with RC.5 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3f08efa35dd334c61127fc8059b4d73b2bd0b866/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L144

As a workaround in previous versions it was common to recreate the form, for example by wrapping it with an `*ngIf="showForm"`, set `showForm` to `true` initially. For recreating, set it to `false`, invoke change detection, set it back to `true` invoke change detection again (by injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` on it)

Comment: Not sure if it works. I guess I assumed `@ViewChild('select') select;` will read the control because of `#select="ngModel"` but I doubt that is the case. I'd suggest you create a new question with the code that demonstrates your exact use case.